# Возможно ли задать увеличение ширины элемента пропорционально уменьшению ширины окна браузера?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Имеется следующий образец кода:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="flex">
 <div class="item item-1">1</div>
 <div class="item item-2">2</div>
 <div class="item item-3">3</div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width: 66%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 110px
}

.item-2 {
  width: 40%
}

.item-3 {
  width: 110px
}
```

Возможно ли в данном случае задать *увеличение* ширины .wrapper пропорционально *уменьшению* ширины окна браузера?
Пен: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVJJwr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width: 66vw
```

подробнее ознакомится можете здесь
https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/